# Java Spring boot scan components from external jar

Tags: java, spring, component-scan

Short proiblem descriotrion

1. i have 2 jar files main-module.jar and sub-module.jar
2. main-module.jar is a spring-boot application
3. sub-module.jar has few components which i want to have in my running main-module application
4. both main-module and sub-module have simillar package structure eg. com.something.mainapp, com.something.subapp
5. @ComponentScan in set to com.something
6. i want to be able to include many JAR files only using the JAVA jut command and scan the via ConponentScan to the spring context

files which i have

[image]

used commands

```
 java -cp sub-module.jar:* -jar .\main-module.jar
```